# How do you set up Kibana alerts?

Tags: json, elasticsearch, boolean, kibana, alert

I have some documents in my index and I wanna get notified if in any document a specific field is set to false.

Can I do this whitin Kibana alerts, or am I just better off running an exists/boolean query to check for what I need that runs everyday?

I have this query:

```
GET my-index/_count
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "product.is_visible": {
              "value": "false"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I want to get notified if this query ever returns more than 0 rows. What would be a good solution?

Answer (score 0):

Using Kibana is a good solution, especially since you can use the [Elasticsearch query rule](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/rule-type-es-query.html#rule-type-es-query).

Then to receive notifications, you can add an action (e.g. send to email) to run when a rule condition is met (e.g. query hits > 0 (threshold value)).